# how to send https post request from esp32 to a website which has post route

Tags: http, https, http-post, httpclient, esp32

I am working on a project where i need to send some readings to be plotted on the website, i have used the native httpClient module to make post request but it wasn't working after a quick search i found
i need to use wifiClientSecure library which supports https request.

this is the code i was using

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "dssdf";  // Enter SSID here
const char* password = "skdjfh";//.. password

//const char* serverName = "monitor.com";
//Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
const char* serverName = "https://...../post_data";

unsigned long lastTime = 0;

unsigned long timerDelay = 2000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
  Serial.println("Timer set to 5 seconds (timerDelay variable), it will take 5 seconds before publishing the first reading.");
}

void loop() {
  
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    //Check WiFi connection status
    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
      WiFiClient client;
      HTTPClient http;
    
      // Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
      http.begin(client, serverName);
      
      
      
      // Specify content-type header
      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
      // Data to send with HTTP POST
      String httpRequestData = "103";           
     
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST(httpRequestData);
      
      
     
      Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
        
      // Free resources
      http.end();
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}
```

i have modified the code using wificlientsecure library

this is the snippet

```
const char* path = "/post_data";

// the SHA-1 fingerprint of the website's SSL certificate
const char fingerprint[] PROGMEM = "b2....................B";

void setup() {
 ............;
  Serial.println("Connected to Wi-Fi");
}

void loop() {
  // Wait for the Wi-Fi connection to be established
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    // Use WiFiClientSecure class to create TLS connection
    WiFiClientSecure client;

    if (client.verify(fingerprint, host)) 
   {  
    // Connect to the server
    if (client.connect(host, 3000)) {
      Serial.println("Connected to server");

      // Construct the POST request
      String data = "123";
      String request = "POST " + String(path) + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                       "Host: " + String(host) + "\r\n" +
                       "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" +
                       "Content-Length: " + String(data.length()) + "\r\n" +
                       "\r\n" +data;

      // Send the POST request
      client.print(request);

      // Wait for the server to respond
      while (client.connected()) {
        String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
        if (line == "\r") {
          Serial.println("Response headers received");
          break;
        }
      }

      // Read and print the response body
      while (client.available()) {
        String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
        Serial.println(line);
      }

      // Close the connection
      client.stop();
      Serial.println("Connection closed");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Connection failed");
    }
  }
  else 
  {
  Serial.println("certificate doesn't match");
 }
 }
  else {
    Serial.println("Wi-Fi not connected");
  }
    delay(10000);
```

i couldn't figure out where i am going wrong, it would be appreciated if someone can tag me to some resource or give suggestions to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

#include "DHT.h"

int value;

const char* ssid = "sdf";  // Enter SSID here
const char* password = "osdf";//.. passwordf wifi network)

const char*  server = " Server url"



const char* test_root_ca= "website certificate"




WiFiClientSecure client;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  pinMode(DHTPin, INPUT);
  dht.begin();

  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
 
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  
}

void loop() {

  value =3212;
  Serial.println("value"+String(value));
  String requestBody = String(value);
  
  delay(1000);
  
  client.setInsecure();
 


  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  if (!client.connect(server, 443))
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");
  else {
    Serial.println("Connected to server!");
   
    client.println("POST  https://url/post_route HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: host of website");
    client.println("content-length:"+ String(requestBody.length()));
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    client.println(requestBody);


    client.stop();
  }

  delay(1000);

  
}
```

i have used this esp32 code to send some random value which is displayed on the website.